# SharePoint 2007 Changing of Site Collection URL

Tags: backup, restore, url, url-rewriting

I want to change the URL of Site Collection **_http://teamnet.com/old** to **_http://teamnet.com/new**.

I found some solution to do the changing of URL via

- backing up the site collection

  ```
  stsadm -o backup -url http://teamnet.com/old -filename oldbk.bak
  ```
- delete the old site collection.

  ```
  stsadm –o deletesite –url http://teamnet.com/old
  ```
- restore the backup file to new site collection.

  ```
  stsadm -o restore -url http://teamnet.com/new -filename oldbk.bak
  ```

The Problem is -

When I restore the backup file to new site collection it say "Another site already exists at '/new'. Choose a new URL, or specify the -overwrite flag to overwrite the existing site."

And If I put -overwrite in end of the restore command the backup file also replaced the content of root site collection **_http://teamnet.com** and in **_http://teamnet.com/new** There is no link but Error and Recycle Bin in Left Navigation Menu.

Could anyone please guide me to properly Backup the specific site and restore the site into new Site Collection URL, Without effecting to Root Site Collection.

Thanks in Advance ~

===================
I've finally found a solution for this case,

1. Back Up the site collection /old
2. Create a new site collection /new
3. Delete /old
4. Delete /new
5. Restore backup file to /new
   ~~~ Now everything working fine .. hope this will helpful to someone ~~~

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an exclusive managed path set for /new?  Make sure you do otherwise a site collection is not allowed to live there and it will overwrite your root site.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) you were missing -overwrite

```
stsadm –o backup –url http://teamnet.com/old -overwrite -filename backup.dat
```

Step 2) delete the site

```
stsadm –o deletesite –url http://teamnet.com/old
```

Step 3) i dont know if it was a typo but you were renaming to the same site? create the new site at the new url

```
stsadm –o restore –url http://teamnet.com/new -overwrite -filename backup.dat
```

that should do the job ;)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262087(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for Quick Reply ~

I just backup the site collection with 'stsadm –o backup –url http://teamnet.com/old -overwrite -filename backup.dat'

and restore with 'stsadm –o restore –url http://teamnet.com/new -overwrite -filename backup.dat' (Included -overwrite) and it end up with updating to root site (http://teamnet.com)

I doubt that using -overwrite in restoring command replace the content of the root site~
Any Idea ?

~in step 3, Yes it is typo error I wanted to use New URL http://teamnet.com/new instead of http://teamnet.com/old.

Thanks anyway ~

Comment: it shouldnt of overwiritten to root site as you stated teamnet.com/new , strange! my code is exacly the same as the following: http://sharepointgod.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/how-rename-sharepoint-2007-site-with.html and http://digantakumar.com/2009/06/23/how-to-change-a-site-collection-url/